# NumPy Array: Minesweeper - substituting random items

Tags: arrays, numpy, random, minesweeper

I am at the beginning of an attempt to make a "minesweeper" game. I have an 8 x 8 array of 0's. I would like to substitute 8 random 0's within the array with the value 1 (to represent "mines"). I have no clue where to begin. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import random

a = np.array([(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)])

for random.item in a:
    item.replace(1)
    print(a)

row = int(input("row "))
column = int(input("column "))

print(a[row - 1, column - 1])
```

How do I replace 8 random 0's within the array with 1's?

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) without replacement option -

```
In [3]: a # input array of all zeros
Out[3]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

# Generate unique flattened indices and on a flattened view of
# input array assign those as 1s
In [8]: a.flat[np.random.choice(a.size,8,replace=False)] = 1

# Verify results
In [9]: a
Out[9]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```